# Read child value from firebase

Tags: android

i want to get only one data from firebase .made lot of efforts but could not be successful 
the structure of the data of my firebase is as follows

[image]

and trying something like this in my code

```
        DatabaseReference myRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users").child("userID");
    myRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            String email = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
            //do what you want with the email
            setDisplayName.setText(email);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            setDisplayName.setText("data not get" + databaseError );
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get only the email you can do something like this :

```
   DatabaseReference myRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users").child("userID");
myRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        String email = dataSnapshot.child("email").getValue().toString();
        //do what you want with the email
        setDisplayName.setText(email);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        setDisplayName.setText("data not get" + databaseError );
    }
});
```

If you dont want to load the other data, you can directly query the email like this :

```
 DatabaseReference myRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users").child("userID").child("email");
myRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        String email = dataSnapshot.getValue().toString();
        //do what you want with the email
        setDisplayName.setText(email);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        setDisplayName.setText("data not get" + databaseError );
    }
});
```