# Read a particular child value from firebase database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to retrieve value(phone number) for a child from my firebase realtime database. However it gives me the following error:

> Attempt to invoke virtual method
>   'com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference
>   com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference.child(java.lang.String)'
>   on a null object reference

The structure of my database looks like this:

```
contactsfirebase-16ade
  users
    -LiKtfTuDQm7LmY49t69
      email: "devsingh0@gmail.com"
      name: "dev"
      phone: "2327272"
```

Code

```
DatabaseReference databaseReference;
databaseReference.child("users").child("userID").child("phone").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener()
{
   @Override
   public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) 
    {
     String phone = dataSnapshot.getValue().toString();

     Phone.setText(phone);
     Phone.getDisplay();
    }
}
```

[Read child value from firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55697150/read-child-value-from-firebase)

I want the value "2327272" to be shown in the textview Phone on my app. However when I click the button it gives the error as shared above and the app crashes.

Comment: can you post your Phone class ?

Comment: Please only use the `android-studio` tag for questions about the Android Studio IDE itself. For questions about Android programming in general, use the `android` tag.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen okay I will keep that in mind next time

Answer (score 1):

Your `DatabaseReference databaseReference;`  is not initialized

Do this

```
DatabaseReference databaseReference; 
databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
databaseReference.child("users").child("userID").child("phone").addListenerForSingleValueEvent...
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I tried this however it still gives the same error. I don't have a class 'Phone' however phone is a string value within the class User. I am trying to retrieve this value in a textview with the id "Phone". Am I missing out on something?

Comment: when you call Phone.setText, is a textview inside your activity? it should have a lowercase name

Answer (score 0):

You can try this method :

```
 @Override
        protected void onStart() {
            super.onStart();
            final DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
//if you retrive the Uid inside of oncreate method you can call it else you have to retrive the Uid
            DatabaseReference veera = rootRef.child("users").child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
            ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    if(dataSnapshot.child("phone").exits()){
                       String phone = dataSnapshot.getValue().toString();
                        Phone.setText(phone);
                  }

                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            };
            veera.addValueEventListener(eventListener);

        }
```

If you are doing in under a button click just move it to a public method and call the method inside of onclicklistener.

```
btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
          //here
      }
      }
```